# Google Oauth2 via Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0

I have been reading a lot about this but not found a decent answer. All I can find is this tutorial: http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1

This is via jsOauth and is for authenticating with Twitter. Is this also possible for Google? Because I want to login with Oauth2..

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late for you, but might help other.

We have made a very simple app using phonegap and google oauth2. *(It uses cordova `2.0.0` but any newer release should work, please refer to cordova release notes.)*

Here is details on how to implement it: http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery

This project is hosted on github: https://github.com/liquidlabs/phonegap-oauth-google-api-mobile

Comment: I have not had any luck with the demo app.  I get to the "loading tasks" screen and do not progress any further.  Are they any known issues?  I've tested on multiple android devices.

Comment: I have just tried the app, seems like there is some issue with JS. Will check if Demo app was built with older version and update here. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Issue has been fixed - which was due to olde GoogleAPI client code (`gapi-client.min.js`). If you are planning to use the code, make sure you use live version from `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js` instead of the offline version we used.

Comment: Awesome.  I look forward to playing around with this soon.  Has the demo apk been fixed?

Comment: Yes, the demo should work now. Just remember, this is demo of Google OAuth2 with phonegap/cordova, and the demo app uses Google Tasks API to pull tasks from `default` list. So, you need to have tasks already added to see list of tasks. I'll update the documentation on project page. Good luck.